# Pandas Dataframe month int to month name in order

Tags: python

I am trying to get the dataframe to print out results in order of the month. If I don't change the month to month name and leave as int (eg. 1: 4, 2: 94) it will be chronological order but the moment I change to month name, it puts in order of months in alphabetical order.

If I do sort=False, it returns me in a random order. Appreciate any help I can get! Thanks!

```
order_group_df = pd.DataFrame({'Property Name': Propertyname, 'Reported on': ReportedDateList, 'Category': Catname})
order_group_df['Reported on'] = pd.to_datetime(order_group_df['Reported on'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce')
order_group_df = order_group_df.dropna()
a = order_group_df.groupby([order_group_df['Reported on'].dt.month.apply(mapper)], sort=False).agg({'count'}).iloc[:, :-2]

print a



Results:        
               count
Reported on     
Feb               94
Mar              306
Jan                4
Jun                9
Aug                6
Sep                2
Oct                2
Nov                1
Apr                1
Jul                5
```

Comment: Why don't you use chronological order as it works, and sorts your month based on 1st, 2nd, 3rd month?

Comment: If I use chronological order, I'm not sure where I should place and apply the month abbr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Categorical` with parameter `ordered=True`. You can define any order you want using `categories` argument.

```
months_order = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"]
cat = pd.Categorical(["Mar", "Feb", "Apr", "Jan"], 
                     categories=months_order, ordered=True)
```

Printing `cat` will give

```
[Mar, Feb, Jan, Apr]
Categories (4, object): [Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr]
```

And printing `cat.sort_values()` will give

```
[Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr]
Categories (4, object): [Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr]
```

EDIT: In your case, you can replace `groupby` argument

```
order_group_df['Reported on'].dt.month.apply(mapper)
```

by

```
pd.Categorical(order_group_df['Reported on'].dt.month.apply(mapper),
               categories=['Jan', ..., 'Dec'],
               ordered=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Pandas` does not do that favor for us. So we need to use a trick.

First of all this is a sample `Dataframe`:

```
df = DataFrame({'month_name': ['Apr', 'Jan', 'Sep', 'Mar'], 'counts': [13, 12, 13, 9]})
print df
```

Its output is:

```
     counts  month_name
0      13        Apr
1      12        Jan
2      13        Sep
3       9        Mar
```

And the trick is to create month number (using `range`) and put it in a dictionary by the key of month name (`%b`).

```
months = {}
for date_idx in range(1, 13):
    month_name = datetime.datetime(2020, date_idx, 1).strftime("%b")
    months[month_name] = date_idx
```

It creates a dictionary that we will use to map into our `Dataframe`.

Now map the result:

```
df["month_number"] = df["month_name"].map(months)
```

In the above we map `Dataframe` based on its name and put month number of the dictionary in `Dataframe` column called `month_number`.

The last step is to sort the `Dataframe` based on its month number as below:

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=['month_number'])
```

The output of the final `Dataframe` would be:

```
     counts  month_name    month_number
1      12        Jan             1
3       9        Mar             3
0      13        Apr             4
2      13        Sep             9
```

You can now remove `month_number` in python way:

```
del new_df['month_number']
```

Or in `Pandas` way:

```
new_df.drop('month_number', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi, after trying this, I get an error because my month_number are all NaN. It also did not process the dt.month

Answer (score 0):

Use **Sort_Dataframeby_MonthandNumeric_cols** function to sort dataframe by month and numeric column:

You need to install two packages are shown below.

```
pip install sorted-months-weekdays
pip install sort-dataframeby-monthorweek
```

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd

from sorted_months_weekdays import *

from sort_dataframeby_monthorweek import *

df = pd.DataFrame([['Jan',23],['Jan',16],['Dec',35],['Apr',79],['Mar',53], ['Mar',12],['Feb',3]], columns=['Month','Sum'])
df
Out[11]: 
  Month  Sum
0   Jan   23
1   Jan   16
2   Dec   35
3   Apr   79
4   Mar   53
5   Mar   12
6  Feb    3
```

To get sorted dataframe by month and numeric column you can used above function.

```
Sort_Dataframeby_MonthandNumeric_cols(df = df,  monthcolumn='Month',numericcolumn='Sum')
Out[12]: 
  Month  Sum
0   Jan   16
1   Jan   23
2   Feb    3
3   Mar   12
4   Mar   53
5   Apr   79
6   Dec   35
```